# How to enable "Snapping" with "Select" interaction in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I've developed an application to support drawing something like lines or points and adding some tags on the map using OpenLayers 3.

Many existing functions in OL3 enable me to draw and modify something.

But, when I select something I drew, I felt the need of a snapping function to make me select them more easily.

Unfortunately, current OL3 supports the snapping only for the drawing and modifying, like below:

```
var draw = ol.interaction.Draw({features: some_features});
var snap = ol.interaction.Snap({featrues: some_features});
map.addInteraction(draw);
map.addInteraction(snap);
```

Actually, I found that the snapping works by replacing *ol.interaction.Draw* to *ol.interaction.Select*, because I can select something I draw if I clicked points apart of them. But, the mouse pointer did not snap to them.

So, How can I implement select interaction with snapping function in OL3?

---

Added some codes to explain details.

See the link: https://jsfiddle.net/keltpower0/sej6z2q4/1/

After you draw some lines, you should click the very point where lines are placed if you select those lines.

I want to more easily select those lines with snapping function, like, if I move the mouse pointer near lines, the pointer "automatically" snap to the lines

Answer (score 1):

Select with snapping sounds a bit weird to me. What about using the [`hitTolerance`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) option of the select interaction ?

Comment: Please read my added comments. I think the function I supposed is not so wired...

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/sej6z2q4/3/ for updated select interaction with `hitTolerance`. Browser don’t allow to move the cursor, so you can’t «snap» the way you want. But with larger `hitTolerance` it’s much easier to select small features.

Comment: Is there any way to enable snapping with select interaction, as in case of draw + snap interaction? like this: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/snap.html